# TClientDataset in Master Detail not closing the detail query

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset

I have 2 ClientDatasets in Master Detail using one provider.
The 2 underlying queries are connected as master detail with a datasource and the master has detail as a field (TDatasetField)

My problem is that closing the master (and even the detail) dataset close the master query but   the detail is not closing... causing problems if we try to repoen the same query later with the same paramaters.

I think the detail query should be closed anyway...

Any help ?

Thanks

Comment: So you assume that closing the one should close the other. Why don't you just write two lines of code instead of one: `Master.Active := false; Detail.Active := false;`  Done.

Comment: Done that already... MCDS.Close; DCDS.Close;  The problem is that the TQuery connected to the DCDS through the provider doesn't close itself... If I request the same data again it will not repoen the detail query as it is already open with the same params! If the data was changed in the database (and it was changed in my case...) it doesn't refresh.  Going to another master record would be fine as the params of the detail would change and it will reopen the query.

Comment: What version of Delphi are you using ? I haven't used ClientDatasets for a while but I modified the default provider some time ago to handle master detail (IMHO) much better. It can be found at http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/24031

Comment: Delphi XE, latest updates... I will give a look at your replacement

Comment: Pascal D: If Clint's suggestion works, then please let him know and he can put this in as an answer for your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue in Delphi XE. It is already in Quality Central (QC) [101264](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=101264).
You can also see about it in EDN's [forum](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=476774&#476774)

The provider should automatically open or close the master and linked detail dataset. So there is no current code to `master.close;` so you could add a `detail.close;` as some comments suggests. If you are using IBX, even the transaction component is not committed when there is a master-detail (QC [107456](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=107456)).

There´s two workarounds:

1. You can add an `detail.close;` in MasterDataset.OnAfterClose event. Note that this is **not** MasterClientDataSet.onAfterClose.
2. You can set in Provider.Options the option `poFetchDetailsOnDemand`. This can have undesirable effect if you don't want the ClientDataSet to only fetch detail's records on demand.